# Problem in a function : appendchild is not a function

Tags: appendchild

I want to make animation on a text, and need to have each letter separated.

This works :

```js
let hero = document.querySelector('.hero');
let text = hero.textContent;
hero.textContent = '';
let letters = text.split('');
letters.forEach((letter) => {
    let newSpan = document.createElement('span');
    let newContent = document.createTextNode(letter);
    newSpan.appendChild(newContent);
    if (newSpan.textContent == ' ') {
        newSpan.style.marginRight = '5px';
        newSpan.style.marginLeft = '5px';
    }
    hero.appendChild(newSpan);
});
```

```html
<div class="hero">My awesome sentence</div>
```

But I would like to use this in another context, so to turn it into a function.
This dosesn't works, message : sentenceDiv.appendChild is not a function

```js
let spanifyText = (sentenceDiv) => {
    let text = sentenceDiv.textContent;
    sentenceDiv = '';
    let letters = text.split('');
    letters.forEach((letter) => {
        let newSpan = document.createElement('span');
        let newContent = document.createTextNode(letter);
        newSpan.appendChild(newContent);
        if (newSpan.textContent == ' ') {
            newSpan.style.marginRight = '5px';
            newSpan.style.marginLeft = '5px';
        }
        sentenceDiv.appendChild(newSpan);
    });
};

let hero = document.querySelector('.hero');

spanifyText(hero);
```

```html
<div class="hero">My awesome sentence</div>
```

It is certainly a newbie problem but cannot figure it out.

Any help please ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `sentenceDiv = ''` overrides `(sentenceDiv) => {}` in the lambda above. See if you can set the content of that div to empty instead of the element itself. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for pointing out the problem !
Just modified html by adding a span with a class for the original text, then removing it at the end of the function. Code can certainly be improved but it does the job !

```js
let spanifyText = (sentenceDiv) => {
    let originalSpan = sentenceDiv.querySelector('.original-span');
    let text = sentenceDiv.textContent;
    let letters = text.split('');
    letters.forEach((letter) => {
        let newSpan = document.createElement('span');
        let newContent = document.createTextNode(letter);
        newSpan.appendChild(newContent);
        if (newSpan.textContent == ' ') {
            newSpan.style.marginRight = '5px';
            newSpan.style.marginLeft = '5px';
        }
        sentenceDiv.appendChild(newSpan);
    });
    originalSpan.parentNode.removeChild(originalSpan);
};

let hero = document.querySelector('.hero');
spanifyText(hero);
```

```html
<div class="hero"><span class="original-span">My Awesome Text</span></div>
```